# nuke tcl in python returns command instead of string

Tags: python, tcl, nuke

In a python script I'm using nuke.tcl() to return a value but I keep getting a runtime error instead of a string:

```
frames = nuke.tcl('[filename [topnode]]')
print (frames)
```

returns:

`RuntimeError: Z:/Project/Sequence/Shot/renders/comp/v001/Shot_v001/Shot_v001.%05d.exr: Unknown command`

So, it returns the result I'm looking for, but then errors out, says it's an unknown command. I've also tried the following but I get the same result

```
frames = str(nuke.tcl('[filename [topnode]]'))
```

Comment: Did you mean `nuke.tcl('filename [topnode]')`?

Answer (score 0):

okay I figured it out. The following returns the string I wanted. I guess "expr" is similar to "eval" in python.

```
frames = nuke.tcl('expr','[filename [topnode]]')
```

Comment: This is `expr` in Tcl: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm

Comment: Take note of @mkrieger1's comment: the Tcl command substitution `[brackets]` *replaces the command with its result*. When you do `[filename [topnode]]`, you're executing the filename command, and then returning the value: then Tcl will attempt to use that value as the command you want to execute. Since you just want the filename, just remove the outer brackets.